# MigrateAsync is creating the SQLite database inside the bin folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

```
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            var loggerFactory = services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
            try 
            {
                var context = services.GetRequiredService<DiscordBotContext>();
                await context.Database.MigrateAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
                logger.LogError(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        await host.RunAsync();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

I have a console application, I want to apply migrations to the SQLite database when the application starts. I decided to do this in the Main method. However, when I run my application the SQLite database gets created in the bin folder, instead of in the console application project (startup project).

Is there a way I can tell `await context.Database.MigrateAsync();` to create it in the startup project?

I never had this problem with ASP.NET Core, but in a console application, the database is being created in the bin folder.

Comment: Are you sure it is being put always in the `bin` directory, or is it going to the current working directory wherever that happens to be, and you are launching the program with `bin` as the current working directory?

Comment: Ah yes that was the problem! I was running start button in Rider IDE, but when I start program with `dotnet run` it worked and placed the database in the startup project :)

Thanks a lot, @BenVoigt you can post this as answer if you like.